# How to print an book in EPUB format?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design

It is an ebook full of illustrations and graphics.
I want it to be printed and also add some pages.

How do I do this on InDesign? Or what should I do since I dont have the raw format of the Ebook.

Comment: ... exactly where does InDesign come in to this?

Comment: @RadLexus I dont know. What do you think?

Comment: I think that you are led to believe you can use InDesign somehow to open and/or edit your e-pub with. That is not the case, however. InDesign can *export* a layout as an e-pub - but it can also export as PDF, PNG, and JPEG, and you cannot open or edit these with it either.

Answer (score 12):

#### Print an .epub book

1. Install free, open source [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/) ebook reader (Windows/Mac/Linux).
2. Click *Add books* and select an .epub book to add to the Calibre library.
3. Select the .epub book that you added and select *Convert books* -> in the *Output format* dropdown list select PDF.
4. Open the PDF book in Adobe Reader or any other PDF reader and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to print the book.

#### Edit an .epub book

An epub file is a zipped collection of files including .html files with formatted text and images. When the epub file is unzipped these files can be browsed by any zip or archive manager application and individually edited.

To access the contents of an epub file for editing follow these steps.

1. Change the extension of the epub file from .epub to .zip.
2. Uncompress the compressed zip file.
3. Open the individual files in the uncompressed zip archive for editing as required.
4. Replace the old files in the zip archive with new or changed files.
5. Save the changes to the zip archive.
6. Change the extension of the zip file from .zip back to .epub.
7. Open the edited epub book in Calibre to review the changes that you have made.
8. Repeat the editing steps if necessary until you have finished editing the epub book.

An average sized epub book usually contains between 20 and 50 embedded html files. I find it convenient to edit all of the html files at the same time in an HTML editor. Of course you will need more than a basic understanding of HTML and CSS in order to do this quickly. There are many different HTML editors to choose from, but most of them are not designed to do this particular task quickly and efficiently. The HTML editor that I recommend is a free, open source application called [Geany](https://www.geany.org/) (Windows/Mac/Linux).

Not only is Geany very fast, but you can also open 50 or more edited .html tabs in Geany in any web browser by selecting all of them in an open archive manager application, and view all of them in a web browser while these are files still open for editing in Geany. If any changes need to be made, they can be made in Geany without having to close Geany first. Before you close the archive manager application, remember to update the archive so that all of the changes to your edited files won't be lost. This method of editing html files simulates the workflow of popular word processors such as Microsoft Word.

Comment: TUrns out theres a file that is a ZIP of the ebook. Its not on epub format. But theres all the HTML files in there. That means thats a good sign right? So thats kind of raw... how do i put it on InDesign?

Comment: That's a good sign. All the text of your ebook is in the HTML files and each image should be a separate file in the archive (usually a .jpg). Instead of InDesign, I recommend using an HTML editor to edit the HTML files.

Comment: I opened the html files, the images are in hi-res! So i think its ok to be printed.. Im still clarifying with the client what she really wants. But she doesnt want to change any text. I think just adding a blank page. And moving some pages. Thats it. I dont know why shes paying me to do nothing? What output should i give to her and where should I do it? I dont think my skill in InDesign is needed for this since thats my job as a freelancer.

Comment: The order of the pages in the epub book is listed in a file that is usually called content.opf in the manifest section of this file. Editing this will change the order of the pages. An HTML file that has two body tags, a beginning tag <body> and an end tag </body> with nothing in between the two body tags will make a blank page.

Comment: I only saw a package.opf.  Its an xml file. I see it listed all the pages html filenames.

But im still so puzzled as to why this client is paying me to do this. She just has to print it. And shes asking me to upload the ebook to lulu, ingramsparks, and i forgot the other one. Shes paying me like 200 bucks

Comment: I think for your epub book the file you need is package.opf and to change the order of the pages you need to change the order of the html filenames in package.opf. Also here's some advice about people who publish books on Lulu or IngramSpark. Frequently these people are consultants or independent businessmen who use their own books as supplementary material to send to prospective clients along with their résumés. Such people may be very knowledgeable, but lack graphic design skills.

Comment: I fully agree with karel's answer - to simply print the book it is easiest to convert to PDF. Calibre does a decent job and you can set relevant options to make the fonts and pages look nice. This is what I do often when I convert `html` files to `epub`, but then sometimes also need to print.